# Is there no SERVER NAME Parameter for BDE in Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, bde

We are migrating a pretty big application crafted in Delphi 5 (still getting customers using this old versions) that uses BDE to connect to a SQL Server. The decided path to migrating is first Delphi 5 to Delphi 2010, then BDE to dbExpress (or dbGO, still undecided).

The problem is that BDE in Delphi 2010 doen't seems to have SERVER NAME parameter! (the one you need to set the host to connect to) and it neither seems to have a replace for that.

I've tried to force it in the strings of parameters unsuccesfuly. I still can not believe this, but maybe I'm missing something bad.

Comment: The BDE has been deprecated for at least 8 years now. At some point you're going to have to pay attention to that fact and realize you need to do something to replace it, because it's going to stop working. You may have just hit that point.

Comment: Sure BDE is deprecated, outdated, arcaic! But this is not my application, I surely wouldn't be using Delphi 5 nowadays. It is from a friend's company. the thing is that we are in such a shock after search for an answer that I take it seriosly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy the old BDE files over the new ones in Program Files\Common files\Borland shared\BDE, you will have access again to SQL servers through BDE. I have done a quick test, and could access my Firebird 2.1 in Delphi 2010 IDE without problem. I still will have to test my application, which was Delphi 6. So I can't give a final conclusion, but it looks OK. If it is wise to continue with BDE maybe questionnable, but at least basically it still works.

Answer (score 2):

BDE support for SQL Links was removed from the BDE.   SQL Server in the BDE was using SQL Links.

The announcement was made in 2002 in this article:
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28688